# Is it possible to build a py2exe console app with the "-i" python argument?

Tags: python, py2exe

I'd like to make a py2exe distribution of a python program that invokes python with the -i command line option. Does anyone know if that's possible?  Also, for this to work, do I need to do something about sys.exit()?

Comment: For the sake of other readers: the `-i` flag to `python` is the "interactive mode" flag, which causes Python to display the interactive prompt after executing your `.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the interactive Python shell by [invoking magic in your script^W^W^W^W manually calling the REPL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395913/python-drop-into-repl) This would be roughly equivalent to the `-i` flag (except you can start the interpreter at ANY time, not just at the end of your script.)

The magic looks like this (courtesy of Jason R. Coombs):

```
def interact():
        import code
        code.InteractiveConsole(locals=globals()).interact()
```