# How to write a python console application with REPL

Tags: python, terminal, console, read-eval-print-loop

I am currently developing a console application in python.It takes commands from the terminal in the format `<my-python-module.py> <command> <other-args>`
However i want to drop into **REPL** and when i write

> my-program

It should do like the fololowing

```
my-program> command 1
my-program> command 2
my-program> exit
good-bye!
```

How do i do that?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395913/python-drop-into-repl-read-eval-print-loop

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmd.html) which gives you "support for line-oriented command interpreters":

> The Cmd class provides a simple framework for writing line-oriented command interpreters. These are often useful for test harnesses, administrative tools, and prototypes that will later be wrapped in a more sophisticated interface

There's also [prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit):

> prompt_toolkit is a library for building powerful interactive command lines and terminal applications in Python.